# netbeans redeploy when resources files changes

Tags: netbeans, deployment, netbeans-8

I'm working on a maven web project, both compile on save and redeploy on save netbeans features are on and they're working when any changes is applied on source code or web pages. however, when I modify resource files located in `src/main/resources` changes are not redeployed and I have to rebuild and redeploy the project manually. it's so painful to do it every single change! is it possible to do it automatically?

Comment: Did you go to the properties of the project then run and check the deploy on save?

Comment: yeah, as I said it is checked and working correctly when any modifications are applied on source code or web pages but not on resource files.